# How to find models to estimate parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

How can I find models for estimating the parameters $w$, $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ in the function:
$y(t)=c_1\sin(wt)+c_2\cos(wt)+c_3$

Comment: Can you add more detail on what $y(t)$ needs to be?

Comment: y(t) is a series of observation datas like
$y(t_i)$ and i=1,2,3....n

Comment: Models aren't for estimating per se; what you want is a *method*. (Also, you tagged least squares... that's a method. Although you might reasonably ask for help implementing it.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I need a process to calculate all the unknowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ data points $(t_i,y_i)$ and you want to fit the model $$y=c_1\sin(wt)+c_2\cos(wt)+c_3$$ which is nonlinear because of $w$.

Suppose that $w$ is given a value; the problem becomes linear and a str=andard multilinear regression would easily provide $c_1,c_2,c_3$ which depend on the value selected for $w$. For this value, you can recompute $$SSQ(w)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(c_1\sin(wt_i)+c_2\cos(wt_i)+c_3-y_i\right)^2$$ Try ddifferent values of $w$ until you see (graph $SSQ(w)$ a a function of $w$) an area where there is a minimum.

Now, you have all required elements to start a full nonlinear regression.

I must mention here that JJacquelin, an MSE user, proposed a  method which does not require any initial guess and any nonlinear regression.
This is explained in the paper *"Régressions et équations intégrales"* (starting on page $21$) published on [Scribd](https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales). The paper is in French but this will not make any problem to you.

**Edit**

Using the $15$ data points used by JJacquelin (page 23 of his paper), the method I described gives the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 w & SSQ(w) \\
 0.5 & 8.3687 \\
 1.0 & 7.2649 \\
 1.5 & 3.8688 \\
 2.0 & 0.3261 \\
 2.5 & 3.2727 \\
 3.0 & 8.7657
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the best point, corresponding to $w=2$, we have from the multilinear regression $c_1=1.28306$, $c_2=-0.573569$, $c_3= -0.397904$. Staring with these estimates, the nonlinear regression leads to $c_1=1.28934$, $c_2=-0.571687$, $c_3= -0.390698$, $w=1.98131$ to which corresponds $SSQ=0.320353$. You can compare with the results of the non-iterative method (page $32$ of the paper - curve $3$). This is indeed a very good method.